# Specifying Video rotation direction on j2me

Tags: video, java-me, rotation, lwuit

I have j2me application in which video is played. On the client device it gets rotated to reverse direction.

What I want to know is whether any method is available for video rotation(to specify the direction of rotation) in LWUIT so as per our application we can rotate the video to the required direction?

Comment: Not getting your question properly @Megha

Comment: Want to rotate video how to do that?

Comment: An understandable question draws better answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you can't do that, but you can take a look at the Advanced MMAPI specification ([JSR 234](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=234)) which might have something.

Comment: _Advanced MMAPI specification_ do you mean [JSR 234 AMMS](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=234)?

Comment: This can be achieve by using the rotated content and give the size to display size minus 1. So video is played in proper orientation.'

Answer (score 1):

You can rotate a video on SonyEricsson JP-7 or higher, as long as I understood
[image]

[image]

Here's the code snippet I used:

```
    //boolean rotate90 indicates whether we want to rotate it

    private void setDisplay(boolean init) {
        if(videoControl == null) return;

        boolean rotate = false;
        trans = Sprite.TRANS_NONE;

        if (rotate90) {
            rotate = true;
            trans = Sprite.TRANS_ROT90;
        }

        if (init) {
            try {
                // video rotate
                videoControl.initDisplayMode(VideoControl.USE_DIRECT_VIDEO | (trans << 4), this);
            } catch (Throwable e) { // not supported by device
                // direct video
                trans = Sprite.TRANS_NONE;
                videoControl.initDisplayMode(VideoControl.USE_DIRECT_VIDEO, this);
            }
        }
        videoControl.setVisible(false);

        int dw, dh;

        //set up target width (dw), and target height (dh) as desired...
        //...
        //...


        try {
            videoControl.setDisplaySize(dw, dh);
        }
        catch(Throwable e) {
            //...
        }
        videoControl.setVisible(true);
    }


    // rotate during playback
    private void rotateVideo() {
        // if we dont't have it, reinit video with new rotation and set current media time
        if (!Main.classExists("com.sonyericsson.media.control.DisplayModeControl")) replayVideo();
        else {
            setDisplay(false); // resize our picture, no init
            // rotate the video.
            com.sonyericsson.media.control.DisplayModeControl dmc = (com.sonyericsson.media.control.DisplayModeControl)player.getControl("com.sonyericsson.media.control.DisplayModeControl");
            dmc.setDisplayMode(rotate90 ? (Sprite.TRANS_ROT90 << 4) : (Sprite.TRANS_NONE << 4));
            dmc = null;
        }
    }

    private void replayVideo() {
        long prevtime = player.getMediaTime();
        play(); //reopen file, Manager.createPlayer, setDIsplay(true), etc.
        try {
            playerPause();
            player.setMediaTime(prevtime);
            playerStart();
        }
        catch(MediaException me) { }
    }
```

Comment: hi, i am using LWUIT framework for crateing UI. So Sprite is not used into that.So this code snippet is not useful in my application